# Reconciling display differences of RPresentation

Tags: rstudio, rpres

RStudio seems to handle display of output slides inconsistently/poorly. How can I control the output so that the saved version of my slides matches what I see in RStudio?

This test document:

```
test
========================================================
author: 
date: 
autosize: true

Exponentials
========================================================

> "...King Shihram asked Sissa ben Dahir what reward he wanted... Sissa said that he would take this reward: the king should put one grain of wheat on the first square of a chessboard, two grains of wheat on the second square, four grains on the third square, eight grains on the fourth square, and so on...

> [The King] ordered his slaves to bring out the chessboard and they started putting on the wheat. Everything went well for a while, but the king was surprised to see that by the time they got halfway through the chessboard the 32nd square required more than four billion grains of wheat, or about 100,000 kilos of wheat... 

> [T]o finish the chessboard you would need as much wheat as six times the weight of all the living things on Earth." - Story of [Ibn Khallikan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Khallikan), _ca_. 1260 AD, [via](http://quatr.us/islam/literature/chesswheat.htm)

<!-- BREAKING UP QUOTE BLOCK -->

> "Humans don't understand exponential growth. If you fold a paper 50 times it goes to the moon and back." - Mark Zuckerberg [via](http://www.kazabyte.com/2011/12/we-dont-understand-exponential-functions.html)
```

Displays like this in RStudio:

[image: A screenshot of the RStudio display of the code given aboe. Three panels are visible. On the left half is the source code. On the right half are two panels; the lower panel is superfluous to this plot. The upper panel shows the tab "Presentation" selected and previews the rendered output of the slide. We can see all of the text written in the code displayed on the slide.]

But when I open it as a standalone HTML page, it's overlarge and the quote box is narrower:

[image: Here the slide is presented again, but it looks slightly different. The text is larger, and the last line of text is not visible.]

I'd like my Rpres to be available without necessarily needing RStudio on the local machine. How can I synergize the output I use to intermediate output with the final product? That is, how can I be more sure of what the slides will look like on export while working in RStudio? What controls do I have at my disposal for manipulating the output of the slides?